# java регулярное выражение для split()

Tags: java, split

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\W]+");
 String[] s = pattern.split("a+aa*-bb-4"); //s = {"a", "aa", "bb", "4"}
все Ок

 String[] s = pattern.split("-a+aa*-bb-4"); //s = {"",  "a" "aa" "bb" "4"}
```

как изменить регулярное выражение чтобы результат был такой

```
s = {"a", "aa", "bb", "4"}
```

т.е. без s[0]=""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Или вместо расщепления выбирать нужные токены с помощью `matcher()`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Main {

    private static String[] extract(String text, String pattern) {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(text);
        while (m.find()) arrayList.add(m.group());
        return arrayList.toArray(new String[0]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] texts = {"a+aa*-bb-4", "-a+aa*-bb-4"};
        for (String txt : texts) System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Main.extract(txt, "\\w+")));
    }
}
```

```
[a, aa, bb, 4]
[a, aa, bb, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Если изменить регулярку, то останутся символы, которые перед первым `\W`. Поэтому просто удалите из результата пустой элемент, если такой имеется и все.

```
public static String[] removeFirstElementIfEmpty(String[] s) {
    if (s[0].equals(""))
        s = Arrays.copyOfRange(s, 1, s.length);
    return s;
}
```